# Underscore loop 2 arrays and match values in template

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have some dummy data with 2 arrays, the arrays will have some duplicated values. In my template I want to compare the 2 arrays and add a visibility class `is-hidden` to any that match as duplicates but I'm not sure how to loop both arrays and do the matching? Can I run `isEqual` against the 2 in some kind of `each loop`?

**Handlebars Template**

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
    <% _.each(mappedSessions, function(session) { %>

       <p class="<% if(session === deleteSessions) { %>is-hidden<% } %>">
           Mapped Entry <u><%= session %></u> Available
       </p>
   <% }) %>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
var data = {
    "id": 1,
    "deleteSessions": ["X0101"],
    "mappedSessions": ["ABC123", "EDF092", "X0101"]
}

var template = _.template($('#tmpl').html());

$('.js-output').html(template(data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case better format data before send it to template

```js
var data = {
    "id": 1,
    "deleteSessions": ["X0101"],
    "mappedSessions": ["ABC123", "EDF092", "X0101"]
}

var template = _.template($('#tmpl').html());
var sessions = _.map(data.mappedSessions, function (session) {
  return {
    isHidden: _.indexOf(data.deleteSessions, session) >= 0,
    value: session
  }
});

$('.js-output').html(template({ sessions: sessions }));
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
    <% _.each(sessions, function(session) { %>
       <p class="<% if (session.isHidden) { %>is-hidden<% } %>">
           Mapped Entry <u><%= session.value %></u> Available
       </p>
   <% }) %>
</script>

<div class="js-output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [intersection](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#intersection)...

```
var duplicates = _.intersection(a, b);
```

This name comes from set theory, where the intersection of two sets is the set of all elements that exist in both sets.